# Android Jetpack Compose androidx.compose.material.SwipeToDismiss suspend fun dismiss(DismissDirection) does not trigger rememberDismissState change

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

My current Android application employs Jetpack Compose `androidx.compose.material.SwipeToDismiss` to support swipe actions on my applications lists.

This all works fine for users swipes, as I have this code to detect swipe direction and react accordingly

```
val dismissState = rememberDismissState(
                        confirmStateChange = { dismissValue ->
                            when (dismissValue) {
                                DismissValue.Default -> doNothing()
                                DismissValue.DismissedToEnd -> onSwipeRight(item)
                                DismissValue.DismissedToStart -> onSwipeLeft(item)
                            }
                            true
                        }
                    )
```

I also have this code for when a user clicks on a list items action button to trigger dismiss as well...

```
IconButton(onClick = { /*TODO*/ }) {
    Icon(
        modifier = Modifier.debounceClickable {
            scope.launch {
                dismissState.dismiss(DismissDirection.StartToEnd)
                onSave(item)
            }
        },
        imageVector = Icons.Default.Save,
        contentDescription = "Save Item"
    )
}
```

I was expecting calling `dismissState.dismiss(DismissDirection.StartToEnd)` would trigger a change in my remembered state and call the associated action. however it doesnt, I have to also call my onSave(item) function as well as triggering the dismiss.

Why is this?
Is my expectation wrong?
Is there any way I can simply call `dismissState.dismiss(DismissDirection.StartToEnd)` to trigger my call to onSwipeLeft(item)?